# How can i know what is the bitmap color size of each pixel?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some bitmap. 
I know that the bitmap format is PixelFormat.FormatXXXXXXbppRgb  => but i want dynamically to calculate the size of each pixel.

For example => if the bitmap pixel format is Format24bppRgb i want to calculate that the R/G/B range is between 0 to 255.

So, i don't know how to get the information that in case of Format24bppRgb the R/G/B bit size is 3.
or that in the format is Format32bppRgb that the R/G/B bit size is 4.

P.S: i don't want to use the code

```
BitmapData bmDateFrame = bitmap.LockBits(....)
Int32 picPixelBit = bmDateFrame.Stride / bitmap.Width;
```

Comment: Byte size, not bit size, you have them mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the 2nd byte (LSB) of the `PixelFormat` value indicates that.

Doing something like this should work:

```
var somepixelformat = ...;

var colorsizeinbits =  (((int)somepixelformat) >> 8) & 0xff;
```